# store glb file in firebase storage programmatically

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Say in android studio, I have a .glb(best 3d model format for firebase) file and I want to store it in firebase storage when users selects it from their phone storage, and then that file should be stored in firebase storage for dynamic activity through java, any way on how to achieve the same?

Comment: any help would be appreciated greatly

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? What is the specific problem you have?

Comment: hey man, thanks for responding, but uhh.... I just figured something, I will need to add this feature but later on, so for now, it's fine, but I will have more questions in the future, so I will contact you that time

Answer (score 0):

save in firebase storage and save the download link in firestore